# Practical use case of in-code encryption/hashing in COBOL/DB2?

Tags: encryption, db2, cobol, mainframe, zos

I am curious about the legitimate use cases of handling encryption or hashing directly within the COBOL/DB2 code without relying on External Security Managers (ESM).

As many may know, a significant portion of security features on an IBM mainframe are facilitated through ESMs such as CA-ACF2, IBM RACF, or CA-Top Secret. These control access to various resources like datasets, transactions, and subsystems including CICS, DB2, IMS, and TSO.

For instance, there's typically no need to verify a password hash via COBOL, as creating an ad hoc user system is redundant when such functionalities are already managed through ESMs as mentioned above.

In my experience, the processes of encryption, decryption, and hashing were not executed within the mainframe, but rather in preceding or succeeding external systems (e.g., PCI-DSS), thus, the applications on the mainframe didn't interact with encrypted or hashed data directly.

On searching "COBOL encryption" online, you'll find various ad hoc encryption routines which, in my opinion, exhibit poor practice both at implementation and design levels.

Sure, there are [some ICSF utilities](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/3.1.0?topic=vdiam-one-way-hash-generate-csnbowh-csnbowh1-csneowh-csneowh1) accessible through COBOL CALL statements for encrypting, decrypting, or hashing data, but can anyone envision a use case where this approach is sensible, and the best practice isn't to rely on an ESM or delegate these tasks to external systems?

Answer (score 1):

ICSF is useful where you are using symetric encryption and you need to keep the key secure and do not want to delegate that work to the application.  ICSF can store the key, manage access and perform the encryption using hardware accelerators for faster processing.

Places where this could be useful is when data is encrpyted in a payload in a REST call or other interface with the COBOL application and the decrypted data  has a policy to be quickly obscured which is an application responsibility.

Further, in terms of users.  ESMs are typically used for access to the mainframe services and systems like CICS, TSO, IMS, etc. and for system adimistration.  Customers are not generally (I don't know of a single use case actually) not defined to the ESM and are identified using other means like a card number, etc.  The ESM doesn't seem to be applicable in this discussion.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on that use case from the app perspective? I mean, you stored the key in ICSF, but how did you retrieve it from COBOL? What encryption algorithms (routines) did you use? If you could elaborate more the functional aspect (something realistic that makes functional sense), I'll award you the bounty. :)

Answer (score 0):

Some valid use cases:-

Hash a credit card number so as enable reporting by individual card with exposing the number (legal requirement in many countries).

An application (say a securities trading platform) may have many external users and you need to manage passwords access without defining every customer to RACF.

Comment: `with -> without`!.  Hash Credit card number? Card space is approximately 2^53, The Titan supercomputer can find it within hour. A single Tesla V-100 can reach 2^49 in one hour. Well, there may be already rainbow  tables around just for this.

Comment: Agree with @kelalaka about hashing card number. In my experience, to fulfill PCI DSS reqs the mainframe received a token and the card information was stored in an external system.

Comment: Regarding the second use case, could you elaborate a bit on the goal for which we would need to verify a user's creds? Wouldn't it make more sense to handle that via Java and use COBOL for the rest of the transactions?